# MySQL Query Results in Memcached For Processing?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, memcached

I am working with tables containing **millions** of records and often have to run queries for reporting reasons against it which some can take hours depending on the level of joins and what not. I know there are lots of ways to optimize queries, but I'm interested in the possibilities of another approach.

Is it possible, via PHP (not natively in MySQL) to take the results of a MySQL query (let's say a "SELECT * FROM table"), store it in Memcached as an array, and then run queries against that cached version? Would it be faster? Roughly, how would that work? By queries I mean, searching an array that may look like:

```
Array[0] {
   Array[0] {
      'field1' => 'value1',
      'field2' => 'value2',
      'field3' => 'value3'
   },
   Array[1] {
      'field1' => 'value1',
      'field2' => 'value2',
      'field3' => 'value3'
   }
   Array[2] {
      'field1' => 'value1',
      'field2' => 'value2',
      'field3' => 'value3'
   }
}
```

Is there a way to "query" PHP arrays more efficiently than allowing MySQL to do the queries? Really this all sounds like a perfect opportunity to make use of NoSQL solutions but, alas, I have no control over that.

**[EDIT]**

We are dealing with data spread out across about 50 databases containing probably 50 tables each with anywhere from 500k to 50 million rows in each. It's all legacy and poorly optimized. Just trying to work with what I've got.

All the databases are on the same slave server and yes, queries need to be done that are cross-database. It's a messy situation that I was just hoping to see if I can maybe handle it better via code than let MySQL do the work (from what I am hearing, the answer is probably **no**)

Comment: How much do you plan on storing in memcached?  Millions of rows or a few thousand rows?  Also, does the memcached run on the same server that your website runs from?  If so, just remember that memory is a limited resource even if your box has a lot of it.

Comment: mysql supports memory tables, although i doubt you need to use them if you just give it a big mem limit.

Comment: The easiest solution would be booting up several servers, install MySQL, use InnoDB for data storage with large `innodb_buffer_pool`, copy the data from old servers to new one and then MySQL would work much quicker. Of course, it probably isn't feasible, but if you are looking to improve MySQL's speed - using InnoDB and larger buffer pools is the answer (on top of having proper indexes and fast CPU for crunching the numbers). Using Memcache is actually **slower** than letting InnoDB handle the in-memory data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of queries that you're running, but most likely, you would see a massive performance drop (not to mention the fact that you would have to load your millions of  rows into memcache to begin with, which would likely take quite a lot of time).  You could run your reports, then store the results into memcache, but that really depends on how often they are accessed along with several other considerations.

Depending on the type of reports you are running, it really should not typically take hours for reporting against only millions of rows.  Have you tried running EXPLAIN against your reporting queries to determine if you are not using proper indexing somewhere, or if you could potentially create a more efficient structure for the type of queries you are running?

Another possibility is that your database server is overloaded, and you might see a better performance gain by setting up a slave server and running your reporting queries against that.

EDIT: 
After getting more information regarding your current unfortunate situation, there are still a couple of possible options.  It is really hard to try to help optimize this situation without having any of the schema or EXPLAIN outputs, but I do think you might be able to improve performance if you carefully analyze all of the queries, and do any possible optimizations (e.g. adding indexes).  It will be tedious.

Another possibility is running the report against each different database separately, then merging the results together somewhere common.

Comment: I know it shouldn't take that long. We are dealing with data spread out across about 50 databases containing probably 50 tables each with anywhere from 500k to 50 million rows in each. It's all legacy and poorly optimized. Just trying to work with what I've got. LOL, thanks. [EDIT] These reports **are** being run against a slave.

Comment: Are the 50 databases all on the same slave server, and are you doing cross-database joins (bad!)?

Comment: @cillosis: You might consider updating your original question to provide more of the details you just gave me in the above comment, and any other information.

Comment: I updated my answer, unfortunately my answer is still not really an answer...and unfortunately anything you do to tackle this is going to be time consuming.  As soon as you guys are able to, you should consider engineering a better solution to handle your reporting needs (I know, I know, it's a serious undertaking that will probably take a year...)

Comment: Oh yeah...an OLAP/OLTP config is in the future for sure.

Answer (score -2):

Memcached is an object level cache. It does not provide a SQL interface. So, your idea is not compatible with memcached. However, there are several possibilities.

For every query you come across, first compute a hash-code. The hash must include all parameters that go into the query. when you retrieve the data, convert the results into a data transfer object (XML/Text etc) and store the hash and data object in memcache.

Now, every time you want to run a query, first create its hash, find if it exists in the cache, if exists, take it, else, fetch from database and put it in the cache.

Issue comes when you update the database, the cache goes stale and you need to refresh it. If your business is such, you can ignore the latest data, you can periodically invalidate the cache. That is, even if the data exists in the cache, but it is fetched 1 hour ago, you will fetch again. This is one strategy.

You can also create a background process that scans the cache and database and refresh it in a pseudo realtime fashion, using triggers in the database. Every update to the database creates a message that will be used to update the cache.

A more complex method is, preprocess all your database updates, and you invalidate the affected cache entries before you make an update.

Caching is easy. Invalidating it is hard. You need to figure out the invalidation before caching the data.

--addendum

sometimes you cannot afford to make a query. the standard jdbc interface is too slow. You will hit a wall where you just cannot make enough calls, so at that point, it is not the database, it is the path to the database. If you want to know more about this, read about handlersocket and how Facebook scales their queries.

http://gigaom.com/cloud/facebook-shares-some-secrets-on-making-mysql-scale/

Handler Socket:

http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.com/search/label/handlersocket

Comment: Query Cache saves on the query execution time only. It does not save the time of preparing query, executing it, getting the data, and converting into a data transfer objects. In the larger scheme of things, actual query execution time is quite less. What is critical is conserving the concurrency to the database. If you use memcached, you do not have to make a call to the DB, hence you do not need to use up a connection. That saved connection will be used to handle another request.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but a connection to memcache is still a connection.  Regardless, he updated his question, he's talking about quite a larger data set than what I perceived initially (when he said "millions" I thought something in the 20-50 million range, he meant several hundred million)

Comment: Memcached connections are socket based, while DB Connections are pool based.

Comment: @srini.venigalla - you do realize that Memcache allows only for 1MB of data to be stored to a single key and that a query that produces the joint data of 50 tables, spanning across hundreds of millions of rows probably won't fit that 1MB. On the other side, InnoDB's caching methods are far, far better and faster than implementing Memcache for working with something of this magnitude.

Comment: You are ignoring my basic point - you cannot afford to make a query. the standard jdbc interface is too slow. You will hit a wall where you just cannot make enough calls, so at that point, it is not the database, it is the path to the database. If you want to know more about this, read about handlersocket and how Facebook scales their queries.

Comment: @NB Getting the data from InnoDB is great, but you need to loop and convert the resultset into some kind of objects. Pojos/xml/html/ whatever. if the data is the same, why recreate these objects? save these objects in memcache and use them. memcache operates at higher level in the food chain.

Comment: @NB Dear Sir, I do not think you have any idea of what you are talking. Query cache is hardly effective in a large scale app. a) They do not work for subqueries, unions, stored functions, now() etc. Just plain selects. They DO NOT work for prepared statements even. Who writes an app w/o Prep Stmts nowadays! Any table in a join on any row, will immediately invalidate the cache, even if that page does not belong in the query. In essence, it is useful only for read only databases, not transactional apps. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/27/mysql-query-cache/

Comment: Here are all the restrictions on when query cache works, when it works. As soon as it works, there will be some update on one of the tables and it gets invalidated. In some cases, query cache reduces the performance because of this constant cache thrashing. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html

Comment: @NB "Parsing a query into something executable by db is infinitesimal amount of processing compared to I/O required to pull all the data" - I am talking about parsing the results, not query!